# Finding the limit of natural logs

Tags: limits

Can someone help me with this problem? I don't know what to do after a certain step...

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{4x - 3} {4x+5}\right)^{4x+1}$$

So far what I have done is take the natural log of both sides and then that takes the exponent out and brings to the front... so then we use one of the natural log rules to get:

$$ ln y = \lim_{x\to \infty} (4x+1)(({ln (4x - 3)})- (ln(4x+5)))$$

This is where I am stuck and have no idea how to continue, what should I do next?

Comment: One way is to rewrite as $\frac{\ln(4x-3)-\ln(4x+5)}{(1/(4x+1)}$ and use L'Hospital's Rule. another way, if you officially know it, is to use the fact that $\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=e^x$.

Comment: Are you allowed to use L'Hopital's Rule?  If so it is not very different from $\lim_{x\to0}x\ln x$.  The one thing that you mustn't do (though it might initially look like a good idea) is to split into two limits - then you will get $\infty-\infty$ which is meaningless.

Comment: Yes, I am allowed. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{4x - 3} {4x+5}\right)^{4x+1} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \left(1 -\frac{8} {4x+5}\right)^{\frac{(4x+1)(4x+5)}{4x+5}} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\left(1 -\frac{8} {4x+5}\right)^{4x+5}\right)^{\frac{4+\frac 1x}{4+\frac 5x}} = (e^{-8})^1 = \frac 1{e^8}$$

Comment: How did you get that exponent up there on the second step?

Comment: Multiplying by $\frac{4x+5}{4x+5} = 1$ won't change anything, right?