# How to find this limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{2x-3}{2x+5}\right)^{2x+1}$ using L'Hospital's Rule

Tags: limits

How to find $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{2x-3}{2x+5}\right)^{2x+1}$$

When I am calculating the limit I get a form like $\infty \times \infty$. I can't continue from that point. I made it as $\frac{\infty}0$. But [L'Hospital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule) can't apply here. Please help me to find the answer. Can you show me the way of doing that one?

Comment: $\log (a^b) = b \log (a)$

Comment: Yes 2x + 1 is the exponent of  (2x-3/2x+5)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134942/how-to-find-the-displaystyle-lim-x-rightarrow-infty-left-fracx-2x-3/2134998#2134998

Comment: Related: [$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{4x - 3} {4x+5}\right)^{4x+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674536/finding-the-limit-of-natural-logs).

Answer (score 6):

@JanEerland gave the solution, but an approach without L'Hospital might be easier.

$$\frac{2x-3}{2x+5}=1-\frac8{2x+5}.$$

Then with $u=2x+5$,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\space\left(\frac{2x-3}{2x+5}\right)^{2x+1}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(1-\frac 8u\right)^{u-4}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(1-\frac 8u\right)^u\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(1-\frac 8u\right)^{-4}\\=e^{-8}\cdot1.$$

Answer (score 3):

Well, we have that:

$$\text{L}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\space\left(\frac{2x-3}{2x+5}\right)^{2x+1}=\exp\left\{\lim_{x\to\infty}\space\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\ln\left(\frac{2x-3}{2x+5}\right)\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{2x+1}\right)}\right\}=\exp\left\{\lim_{x\to\infty}\space\frac{\frac{16}{4x^2+4x-15}}{-\frac{2}{\left(1+2x\right)^2}}\right\}$$

And now you can use:

$$\frac{\frac{16}{4x^2+4x-15}}{-\frac{2}{\left(1+2x\right)^2}}=-8\cdot\frac{\left(1+2x\right)^2}{4x^2+4x-15}$$

So:

$$\text{L}=\exp\left\{-8\lim_{x\to\infty}\space\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\left(1+2x\right)^2\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(4x^2+4x-15\right)}\right\}=\exp\left\{-8\lim_{x\to\infty}\space\frac{4\left(1+2x\right)}{4+8x}\right\}$$

And now you can use:

$$\frac{4\left(1+2x\right)}{4+8x}=1$$

So:

$$\text{L}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\space\left(\frac{2x-3}{2x+5}\right)^{2x+1}=\exp\left(-8\cdot1\right)=\frac{1}{e^8}$$

Comment: What is the meaning of exp?

Comment: @user6332995 $$\exp\left(x\right)=e^x$$

Comment: There is no real need for a second application of L'Hospital. Ratios of polynomials are trivial to solve (like you did next).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did that, because the OP said in his question that he wants to use L'Hospitals rule!

Comment: @JanEerland: why didn't you use it a third time, then ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's a good question :) because after the second time it became to obvious what the answer will be

Comment: As you know, my point is that it was already obvious one step earlier.

Comment: @YvesDaoust then tell me your answer also. Even if it doesn't use l'hospital rule it's ok.

Comment: @user6332995: hem, it's in front of your eyes.